# Provide default value for constructor initializing reference instance variable

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I have a class `Foo` that has a reference to `Bar` as an instance variable.  Is there a way to have one of the `Foo` constructors create a `Bar` instance (so users of the `Foo` class need not explicitly create a `Bar` object themselves)?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Foo {
  private:
    int size;
    Bar& bar; // shared by other objects
    //several other instance variables

  public:
    Foo(int s, Bar& b) : size(s), bar(b) {}

    // This, of course, doesn't work.  I can't think of an 
    // alternative that doesn't require users of Foo to 
    // create Bar
    Foo(int s) : size(s), bar(Bar(s)) {}
}
```

(In "real life", `Foo` and `Bar` are more complicated.  `Bar` is a friend of `Foo` that has a private constructor used only by `Foo`.  Each `Bar` can be shared by several `Foo`s. This isn't a major problem, I'm just curious if it can be done without pointers.)

Comment: one dirty solution is that you can have a static member of bar type in foo class, and provide it in second constructor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to allocate a `Bar` if and when you need one. Adding a member `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` is the easiest way of achieving this. I can't conceive of a system that addresses your problem that will not add some memory overhead to your class. You either have to account for storage for a `Bar` even when it isn't needed or you have to account for some state to track rather or not your `Bar` is internally managed. Using a `unique_ptr` adds the size of a pointer to your class.

```
#include <memory>

class Foo {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> storage;
    Bar& bar;
    int size;

public:
    Foo(int s, Bar& b) : bar(b), size(s) {}
    Foo(int s) : storage(std::make_unique<Bar>(s)), bar(*storage), size(s) {}
};
```

A more elaborate solution could be to provide a wrapper for `Bar` that provides a default constructor that takes care of initializing a new instance.

Note that in your example, you do not initialize the member in the same order as they are declared. Members will be initialized *in the order they are declared* regardless of how you order them in your initialization list.

Comment: Good catch.  I fixed the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // This, of course, doesn't work.  I can't think of an 
> // alternative that doesn't require users of Foo to 
> // create Bar
> Foo(int s) : size(s), bar(Bar(14)) {}
> ```

You can use a default `Bar` object, which can be a `static` member variable of `Foo` or any other class that can provide such an object.

E.g.

```
class Foo {
   private:
      Bar& bar; // shared by other objects
      int size;
      //several other instance variables

      static Bar& getDefaultBar();

   public:
      Foo(int s, Bar& b) : size(s), bar(b) {}

      Foo(int s) : size(s), bar(getDefaultBar()) {}

}

Bar& Foo::getDefaultBar()
{
   static Bar b(24);
   return b;
}
```

Comment: That works if I only ever want one Bar object.  I didn't mention it above; but, that's not the case here.

Comment: @Zack, in that case, [the answer by François Andrieux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42098394/434551) should work.

Answer (score 0):

If every `Foo` shall have it's own individual `Bar`-object (not a single shared one), then you could try the following:

```
class Foo {
private:
    Bar& bar; // shared by other objects
    int size;
    Bar* defaultBar;
    //several other instance variables

public:
    Foo(int s, Bar& b) : size(s), bar(b), defaultBar(nullptr) {}
    Foo(int s) : Foo(s, *(new Bar(14))) { defaultBar=&bar; };
    virtual ~Foo() {
        if (defaultBar)
            delete defaultBar;
    }
    void setBar(Bar &b) {
        if (defaultBar)
            delete defaultBar;
        defaultBar = nullptr;
        bar=b;
    }
};
```

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: This solution feels very error prone. Example, how do you know rather or not to delete the address of `bar` in the destructor?

Comment: @François Andrieux: yes, that's of course an issue, which must (and can) be handled. If, however, the requirement is that every Foo shall have it's own default bar, then one has to deal with replacing / freeing the default bar once not used any more. Right?